# 'function' object has no attribute 'objects' in django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

i am getting a error:
AttributeError at /
'function' object has no attribute 'objects'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 3.2.5
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:
'function' object has no attribute 'objects'
Exception Location: G:\PYTHON DJANGO 2021 - COMPLETE COURSE\first_django_project\devsearch\project\views.py, line 27, in projects
Python Executable:  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\djangoenv\python.exe
Python Version: 3.9.6
Python Path:
['G:\PYTHON DJANGO 2021 - COMPLETE COURSE\first_django_project\devsearch',
'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\djangoenv\python39.zip',
'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\djangoenv\DLLs',
'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\djangoenv\lib',
'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\djangoenv',
'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\djangoenv\lib\site-packages']
Server time:    Sat, 21 Aug 2021 13:18:04 +0000

```
# models.py
from django.db import models
import uuid


# Create your models here.
class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)
    demo_link = models.CharField(max_length=2000,null=True,blank=True)
    source_link = models.CharField(max_length=2000,null=True,blank=True)
    tag = models.ManyToManyField('Tag',blank=True)
    vote_total = models.IntegerField(default=0,null=True,blank=True)
    vote_ratio = models.IntegerField(default=0,null=True,blank=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4,unique=True,primary_key=True,editable=False)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


# views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Project


# Create your views here.
def projects(requests):
    projects = Project.objects.all()
    return render(requests,"project/projects.html", {'projects':projects})
```

Comment: Did you define a view with the name `Project` in your file?

Comment: I suggest you to proper format your question to make other help you with this issue. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You likely defined a function in your views named `Project`, as a result the reference to the `Project` model is altered to the view function.

You can define a view function name in lowercase, so `project` instead of `Project`, and thus implement this as:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Project

# Create your views here.
def projects(requests):
    projects = Project.objects.all()
    return render(requests, 'project/projects.html', {'projects':projects})

# project instead of Project
def project(request, pk):
    # …
```

Answer (score 0):

try migrating the database

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```